# Error performing resource injection on glassfish

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, ejb

This is my problem:
I'm learning Java EE development and I wanted to build up a WebApplication using Ejb. First of all I tried developing on the same machine, creating a EJB module on a glassfish domain and accessing it through a web application running on the same machine but on different domain: all worked fine. I was able, using glassfish 3.1, to access to the EJBmodule from the webapp thanks to the definition of glassfish-web.xml in my WEB-ING folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
  <ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/FirstBeanRemote</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:127.0.0.1:3700#java:global/EJBModule/FirstBean!ejb.FirstBeanRemote</jndi-name>
  </ejb-ref>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

After this, I wanted to change experiment, using different machines for the ejb module and the webapp. First of all I installed on a debian machine glassfish 3.1 and deployed my module including the required interfaces. No errors returned in the deploying so I proceeded starting the domain and again all seems to work fine. In server.log I copied the portable jndi names for my EJB FirstBean:

```
Portable JNDI names for EJB FirstBean: [java:global/EJBModule/FirstBean, java:global/EJBModule/FirstBean!ejb.FirstBeanRemote]
```

So now on another machine using Netbeans ( under windows 7 ) I created the same webapp as the previous one just changing the glassfish-web.xml in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
  <ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/FirstBeanRemote</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:192.168.1.110:3700#java:global/EJBModule/FirstBean!ejb.FirstBeanRemote</jndi-name>
  </ejb-ref>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I'm sure about Ip(static in my lan) and port (I create a default domain on glassfish).
The problem comes now. When I start the webapplication I get the error:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean prova
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:211)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Eccezione durante il tentativo di inserire Remote ejb-ref name=ejb/FirstBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =ejb.FirstBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=corbaname:iiop:192.168.1.110:3700#java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean!ejb.FirstBeanRemote,refType=Session in class ciao.Prova: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/ejb/FirstBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:205)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Eccezione durante il tentativo di inserire Remote ejb-ref name=ejb/FirstBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =ejb.FirstBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=corbaname:iiop:192.168.1.110:3700#java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean!ejb.FirstBeanRemote,refType=Session in class ciao.Prova: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/ejb/FirstBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:703)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:470)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:184)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/ejb/FirstBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=ejb/FirstBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =ejb.FirstBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=corbaname:iiop:192.168.1.110:3700#java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean!ejb.FirstBeanRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'corbaname:iiop:192.168.1.110:3700#java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__' [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Buono: IOP00100009: string_to_object conversion failed due to bad schema specific part in name java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 9  completed: No]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:599)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=ejb/FirstBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =ejb.FirstBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=corbaname:iiop:192.168.1.110:3700#java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean!ejb.FirstBeanRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'corbaname:iiop:192.168.1.110:3700#java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__' [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Buono: IOP00100009: string_to_object conversion failed due to bad schema specific part in name java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 9  completed: No]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:191)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:169)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Buono: IOP00100009: string_to_object conversion failed due to bad schema specific part in name java:global/EJBModule123/FirstBean__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 9  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy151.soBadSchemaSpecific(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.resolveCorbaname(INSURLOperationImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.resolveINSURL(INSURLOperationImpl.java:154)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(INSURLOperationImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.string_to_object(ORBImpl.java:976)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:184)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFoundHelper.read(NotFoundHelper.java:72)
    at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextExtStub.resolve_str(_NamingContextExtStub.java:165)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.resolveCorbaname(INSURLOperationImpl.java:222)
    ... 68 more
```

It seems to me a jndi problem, infact in the exception list I can read "Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/ejb/FirstBeanRemote', so the webapp is not even able to access to the EJBModule. But I'm wondering why, since I'm using the portable jndi provided me by the glassfish server itself!

I hope I was clear and someone can help me.

Max

Comment: can you add -Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBdebug=giop to your domain and check if this actually is a jndi problem or if a corba error is hidden behind?